# Comparing a string not working when it seems it should

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

When i NSLog the contents of my string it outputs:

```
m3u8
```

as expected. Because thats what I parse into the string.

Later when I do some compare to check is the string equal to m3u8 they fail.

```
NSRange match;
match = [aRadio.streamType rangeOfString: @"m3u8"];
if (match.location == NSNotFound) 
{
    NSLog(@" m3u8 Not MATCHED: %@",aRadio.streamType);
    //break;
}

if ([aRadio.streamType compare:@"m3u8" ] == NSOrderedSame)
{

    NSLog(@" m3u8 DETECTED: %@",aRadio.streamType);
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"NO m3u8 DETECTED %@",aRadio.streamType);
    [self createStreamer];
    [streamer start];
}
```

The NSLogs show that there is a match from the first check and no detection for the 2nd check.

I would expect them both to see that the string contains m3u8 as confirmed by what is output by Radio.streamType in the NSLogs.

This is how i declared stramType

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *streamType;
```

Anybody able to explain where this odd behavior is coming from?

Thanks
-Code

EDIT

```
NSLog(@"Str len: %d",[aRadio.streamType length]);
```

outputs 5 as the length.

I try and trim the string here of newlines

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{ 

if(!currentElementValue) 
{
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
}
else
{   
    [currentElementValue appendString:string];
    [currentElementValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet 
newlineCharacterSet]];
    [currentElementValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet 
whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    [currentElementValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet 
controlCharacterSet]];
    [currentElementValue stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet 
nonBaseCharacterSet]];
    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);
}   
}
```

but NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue); still drops to a newline to display whats contained in currentElementValue which is 'm3u8'

Thanks
-Code

Comment: Have you looked for whitespace/nonprintable characters in the string? (ie. length != 4)

Comment: Hiya, you were right about the length. Added an EDIT expanding on it. Thanks for the tip Cam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to attempt literal comparisons using something like `isEqualToString:`. There are of course more advanced options which introduce parameters for locale, diacratics, case insensitive, and so on -- it depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

try comparing strings by

```
if ([aRadio.streamType caseInsensitiveCompare:@"m3u8"] == NSOrderedSame)
```